# How can I solve this problem with array.prototype?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm in a little trouble here. Can't really resolve this problem, I've been using this solution:

```
 Array.prototype.all = function(callback){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
      if(this[i] < 10) return true;
  }
      if(this[i] < 2) return false;
    }
}
```

But it does not work. I know I'm making a rookie mistake (I'm new to learning javascript), and would love a little help on this.

**The problem in question is this one:**

```
function all(fn) {
      // Write a function called all in the Array prototype,
      // that receives a function (callback). Assume fn always returns true or false.
      // The function all must return true if fn returns true when we invoke it passing all the elements of the array one by one
      // the function all must return false, if any element of the array causes fn to return false;
      // E.g:
      // [1,2,3].all(function(elem) {
      //    return elem < 10;
      //  });
      // returns true
      // [1,2,3].all(function(elem) {
      //    return elem < 2;
      //  });
      // returns false.
    }
```

Comment: Please tell us what is not working and what you are trying to achieve :) By the way have a look to the .every function > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: format you code and you'll see the issue immediately

Answer (score 2):

You only have to return `true` if the returned value from `callback` is `false` else `return true`

```js
Array.prototype.all = function (callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        const result = callback(this[i]);
        if (!result) return false;
    }

    return true;
};

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 300, 0];
const arr2 = [1, 0];

console.log(arr1.all((elem) => elem < 2));
console.log(arr2.all((elem) => elem < 2));
```

**`ADDITIONAL INFO`**

`Array.prototype` already has [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method that will the exact same thing

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 300, 0];
const arr2 = [1, 0];
console.log(arr1.every((elem) => elem < 2));
console.log(arr2.every((elem) => elem < 2));
```